# The message box

Tags: android

we all have seen how the message app looks like in an iphone.The messages which a user sends are displayed in a glossy green color field,plus they are un editable, the un editable part is understood, but how does the whole edit text field become's green in color, 
I am making an application which uses this feature, could some one please help me out with this?I'd really appreciate the effort.Thanks:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the TextView component inside for example RelativeLayout and set background color for layout as green.